# Tag synonym suggestions - need voters!

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

I put in a few tag synonym suggestions I'd love to get feedback on and/or get votes on:

[breastmilk](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/breastmilk) -> [breastfeeding](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/breastfeeding) (the latter tag guidance says it includes questions about breastmilk, and we only got 2 questions tagged [breastmilk](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/breastmilk) in the past year)

[parenting](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parenting) -> [parents](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parents) (Parenting is probably misused for the most part - after all this is Parenting.SE, so all questions should have this - and making it a synonym to Parents might be the easiest solution, as that has usage guidance that should help keep it from being misused)

There's also a longstanding one from Erica out there still that could use a few votes:

[arguments](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arguments) -> [conflict](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conflict)

I'm going to keep going through tags that don't have wikis, and will probably have some more suggestions. I'll add them to this list, but you can always go to the [tag synonym page](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms?filter=suggested&tab=newest), also available from Tags -> bottom of the page `tag synonyms` link, and then select `suggested`, to see what needs votes.

For those that don't know - you need a total answer score of 5 in the tag to vote on the synonym (I don't think you need a particular amount of rep; 1250 is needed on a beta site to *suggest* the synonym, though).   See [suggesting tag synonyms](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms) for more information!

Comment: The parenting tag itself probably just needs to be burninated.

Comment: @Becuzz I certainly don't disagree with that.

Comment: Do we need an *in loco parentis* tag?

Comment: I agree with Becuzz - it should rather be burninated. It's not a synonym of *parents* as the latter is often used when children ask how to deal with their parents, for example.

Comment: @anongoodnurse How do we burninate on the site? Is it a moderator task or a SE staff task?

Comment: It's been a while since I sorted out tags, but I remember burninating them myself. :)

Answer (score 1):

I edited all the question with [parenting](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parenting), removing it. Now, only this [question](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/34449/30519) (*on hold*, no answers) remains. So the issue should be resolved in a few days without any further action necessary. This way, there was a chance to re-tag the questions or fix some other, minor issues. As was to be expected, [parenting](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parenting) is superfluous.

However, [parents](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parents) is not and only once a suitable substitute (in case of this duplicate [question](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/31282/30519)). It should not be a *tag synonym* of [parenting](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parenting) as it's useful in case it's about the parents themselves or if the question is from a child's perspective.